# Optical effect on the perceived dimensions of the mountains

Tags: optics

Could you tell me what optical effect it is? It also happens to me live.

Normal mountain size.

[image]

Optical effect.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure no photoshop is involved in either of the pictures?

Comment: These are the same buildings and the same mountains in each photo, just taken with different focal length lenses?

Comment: You might want to ask this on the photography stackexchange instead of physics.

Comment: This is just the focal length of the camera. I think your question is answered here https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/understanding-focal-length.html

Comment: Please be more specific about *what effect exactly* you are asking about and what the difference is in how the two pictures you are showing here were obtained.